# My javascript program isnt working

Tags: javascript, html, css

i made a random number gen thingy, and I made it so that it changes the picture in the background. it can be 1 of 2 numers. her's the code (1st css, then html

```css
/* Basic Styles */
body {
    background-color: #FBFBFB;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'font', sans-serif;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: font; src: url('font.ttf');
}
/* Hero Styles */
#hero{
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 65vh;
    background-position: center -550px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
#hero-title{
    font-size: 5em;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Hello
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <link rel='shortcut icon' href='images/favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon' />
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var hero=Math.random()
            hero = (hero * 2)
            hero = Math.floor(hero) + 1

            console.log("Hero is number " + hero + " of 2.")
            if (hero == 1) {
               document.getElementById("hero").innerHTML.style.background-image="images/hero1.png"
            }
        </script>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="hero">
            <div id="hero-title">
                awesome websogte
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

so yah, I need to know how to change da hero's background image. (in the if sstatement)

Comment: Why do you have a nested if statement which asks the same thing as the inner one?

Comment: oops, messed up there, doesnt really interfeer tho

Comment: i fixed it now.

Comment: This title is really vague. Can you make it more descriptive of your problem?

Answer (score 2):

There's 3 errors in the line of code that's supposed to set the background image. Fix that and it will work.

1: Set 'element.style' instead of 'element.innerHTML.style'.

2: Change 'background-image' to 'backgroundImage'. ([w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp))

3: Wrap the image link in 'url()'.

**Old:** `document.getElementById("hero").innerHTML.style.background-image="images/hero1.png"`

**New:** `document.getElementById("hero").style.backgroundImage="url(images/hero1.png)";`

Comment: ok, now it says cannot read property "style" of null

Comment: That's because the javascript is executed before the DOM is loaded. Try execute it once the DOM or the page is loaded, or place the script at the bottom of the page.

Comment: here's a screenshot https://imgur.com/a/RAFLu

Comment: YEAH THANK YOU!!! I JUST GOT IT!!!

Comment: Haha, you're welcome. ;)